# Show different Icons for mutliple Markers from a Data Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a data array as below, which can be shown on Google Maps by button click::

```
var locations = [
[50.6343356475971,-9.53181026267496,"small_red","AGH","AGH1","GAS25"],
[40.2185001907869,0.928586419184371,"meassle_grey","BES1","BES","GAS23"],
[52.1400374749101,-7.50501915638024,"small_blue","DUB1","DUB","GAS24"],
```

to define the icon per class I tried the following without success:

```
function selectIcon(locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {      //Loop trough List of Data
  if (locations[i][2] ==  "small_red") {
    iconIMG = new google.maps.MarkerImage("Link to the iconAAA.png");
  if (locations[i][2] ==  "small_blue") {
    iconIMG = new google.maps.MarkerImage("Link to the iconBBB.png");
  };
```

The problem is now that for all 3 locations always "iconBBB.png" is shown for all markers.

Answer (score 0):

so where is your problem? the code looks fine, just omit the semicolon after the if (but that should not be the problem:

```
if (locations[i][2] ==  "small_red") {...};  // <-- remove the semicolon here
```

you also need to call your function somewhere:

```
selectIcon(locations);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is always shows the last icon-type defined for all location markers